# Kubernetes cron job needs one command to finish first?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cron job that creates a zip file which takes about 1 hour. After it's completion I want to upload this zip file to an AWS s3 bucket.

How do I tell the cron job to only do the s3 command after the zip is created?

Should the s3 command be within the same cron job?

Currently my YAML looks like this:

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: create-zip-upload
spec:
  schedule: "27 5 * * *" # everyday at 05:27 AM
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mycontainer
            image: 123456789.my.region.amazonaws.com/mycompany/myproject/rest:latest
        args:
        - /usr/bin/python3
        - -m
        - scripts.createzip
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't have a concept of a relationship between resources. There isn't an official or clean way to have something occurring in one resource cause an effect on another resource.

Because of this, the best solution is to just put the s3 cmd into the same cronjob.

There's two ways to do this:

1. Add the s3 cmd logic to your existing container.
2. Create a new container in the same cronjob that watches for the file and then runs the s3 cmd.

Comment: If I go with the first option of having the adding the s3 command, do I make it as a separate 'spec'? Was thinking to have the s3 command try to upload it every 10 minutes, until it finds the file and successfully uploads it, after that have the cronjob finish.

Comment: If possible, I would recommend building a container that has a bash script containing all your logic and call that. Alternatively, you could try to inline a bash script into your `spec.template.args`, but the result will likely be atrocious.

Comment: Looks like that will work... I have a bash script that calls the python code to create the zip, following that I have a while loop which sleeps until the presence of that zip file, and then uploads it to s3 when it exists. I will modify the cron job to call the shell script rather than the python code. Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamRoss the second one sugested by Swiss is the best one, called sidecar container